# Add expression field to layer_1 to track id of polygon in layer_2 which is closest to line feature in layer_1 PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I just learned about the addExpressionField function which should be handy for my use case as I need to keep track of some info for a layer that is loaded in from postgres. I have a lines layer and a polygon layer and in the line layer I want to add a virtual field that keeps track of the closest polygon in the polygon layer. I'm hoping that some distance calc will work and in particular for cases where a line intersects with multiple polys hopefully it will go with the one of most intersection. So my field definition will be:

```
field = QgsField('ID_of_closest_poly', QVariant.Int)
```

And then I need help with filling this out as I am new to expressions:

```
layer.addExpressionField(' ?? ', field)
```